# How to write 7-digit numbers in German words?

Tags: numbers

It would be very helpful if you solve 3598462.

Answer (score 5):

Your example is written as

> drei Millionen fünfhundertachtundneunzigtausendvierhundertzweiundsechzig.

Up to 999'999, numbers are written in one word. The powers of 1000 from a million upwards are nouns and therefore capitalized. (Million, Milliarde, Billion, Billiarde etc.)

Reference: [Wikipedia. Schreibweise von Zahlen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreibweise_von_Zahlen) especially section [Große Zahlen in Wortform](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreibweise_von_Zahlen#Gro.C3.9Fe_Zahlen_in_Wortform).

Comment: I can not suggest an edit directly: "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"

Since numbers normally are written in lower case, you should edit:
`Drei Millionen fünfhundertachtundneunzigtausendvierhundertzweiundsechzig.`
into
`"drei Millionen fünfhundertachtundneunzigtausendvierhundertzweiundsechzig"`

No reason to provide an own answer, since there's nothing else to be added to your answer.

Comment: @Quasimodo’s clone: _Drei_ is the first word here, though; that’s why it is capitalized.

Comment: Of course, however, it is not a full sentence. Therefore I have enclosed the suggested phrase in quotes. And the more important reason: People looking for an answer are not able to distinguish if it is written upper case here just in order to a start of phrase or if you should capitalize it generally. Thus I suggest writing it correctly in general case and enclose it in quotes. It should be obvious to anyone leaving no questions.

Comment: Alternatively you could use ``backticks(`)`` to form it as code segment.

Comment: @Quasimodo’s clone: Code markup should not be used except for, well, code. Among other things, it causes screenreaders for the blind to no longer interpret it as words to be read.

Comment: Just to add an important fact especially for people from outside europe. If you have a number with 10 or more digits, you must remember, that 1.000.000.000 is *not* »eine Billion«! It is »eine Milliarde«. »Eine Billion« is 1.000.000.000.000, this is what you call in the US »one trillion«! So be careful with translating big numbers!